# Why doesn't the onListItemClick function in the ListFragment fire when I add a button or edittext to the item?

Tags: java, android, xml, list, fragment

I render each element of my ListFragment with two buttons and edittext, but in this case, onListItemClick does not work for me. And as soon as you hide the buttons and edittext in the adapter, everything immediately starts working, I think that this is some kind of conflict between the fields, but I don’t know how to fix it. I will be grateful for any help.

My adapter:

```
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ProductsModel> {
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private int layout;
private ArrayList<ProductsModel> productsList;
private String nameFragment;

private Parsers parser;


public ProductAdapter(Context mContext, int resource, ArrayList<ProductsModel> products, 
String nameFragment) {
    super(mContext, resource, products);
    this.productsList = products;
    this.layout = resource;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    this.parser = new Parsers(mContext);
    this.nameFragment = nameFragment;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(this.layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    final ProductsModel products = productsList.get(position);

    PricesModel price = parser.PriceParser((int) products.getId());

    viewHolder.imageProduct.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
    viewHolder.imageProduct.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_START);

    viewHolder.nameProduct.setText(products.getName());
    viewHolder.categoryProduct.setText("Group");
    viewHolder.priceValueProduct.setText("Cost: "+price.getPriceValue());
    viewHolder.countProduct.setText("0");

    if(nameFragment.equals("ListProduct")){
        viewHolder.priceValueProduct.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.countProduct.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.buttonPlus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.buttonMinus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    final ImageView imageProduct;
    final TextView nameProduct, categoryProduct, priceValueProduct;
    final EditText countProduct;
    final Button buttonPlus, buttonMinus;
    ViewHolder(View view){
        imageProduct = view.findViewById(R.id.imageProduct);
        nameProduct = view.findViewById(R.id.nameProduct);
        categoryProduct = view.findViewById(R.id.categoryProduct);
        priceValueProduct = view.findViewById(R.id.priceValueProduct);
        countProduct = view.findViewById(R.id.countProduct);
        buttonPlus = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
        buttonMinus = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonMinus);
    }
}
}
```

My fragment:

```
public class ListProducts extends ListFragment {

private ProductAdapter mProductAdapter;
private Parsers parser;
private Context mContext;
private View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_products, container, false);
    mContext = getContext();
    parser = new Parsers(mContext);

    ArrayList<ProductsModel> productsList = parser.ProductsParser();

    ArrayList<ProductsModel> improveProductsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < productsList.size(); i++){
        improveProductsList.add(productsList.get(i));
    }
    EditText searchProduct = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);
    searchProduct.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String nameProduct = s.toString();
            if(count != 0) {
                improveProductsList.clear();
                for (int i = 0; i < productsList.size(); i++) {
                    if (productsList.get(i).getName().toLowerCase().indexOf(nameProduct.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                        improveProductsList.add(productsList.get(i));
                    }
                }
            }else{
                for(int i = 0; i < productsList.size(); i++){
                    improveProductsList.add(productsList.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });

    try {
        int idCompany = getArguments().getInt("idCompany",0);
        int idStore = getArguments().getInt("idStore", 0);
        mProductAdapter = new ProductAdapter(mContext, R.layout.simple_list_item_product, improveProductsList, "NewOrder");
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        mProductAdapter = new ProductAdapter(mContext, R.layout.simple_list_item_product, improveProductsList, "ListProduct");
    }
    setListAdapter(mProductAdapter);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(@NonNull ListView l, @NonNull View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    Log.d("TAG", ""+position);
}
}
```

XML simple_list_item_product:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageProduct"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="100sp"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutInfoAndButtonProduct"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nameProduct"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Name prod"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/categoryProduct"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Category prod"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf = "@+id/nameProduct" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/priceValueProduct"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:text="Cost prod"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf = "@+id/nameCompany" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"/>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/countProduct"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="+" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

XML fragment_list_products:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_list_products"
tools:context="com.example.rbsoftsalesmobile.ui.productsscreen.ListProducts">

<TextView
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/game_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
    android:text="List prod"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Search"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/game_title"
    android:layout_margin="5sp"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchEditText" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The callbacks belongs to the buttons and/or edittext may have *overriden* the callback belongs to ListFragment. This is what mostly happens in your case.

Comment: Please select your answer as the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with setFocusable(false), for every element that can intercept input from other components like Button, EditText, CheckBox and others.

```
if(nameFragment.equals("ListProduct")){
        viewHolder.priceValueProduct.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.countProduct.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.buttonPlus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.buttonMinus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    viewHolder.countProduct.setFocusable(false);
    viewHolder.buttonPlus.setFocusable(false);
    viewHolder.buttonMinus.setFocusable(false);
    return convertView;
}
```